# Nim: How to check if a float is nan or inf?

Tags: nim-lang

How can I check if a float variable is `NaN` or `inf`. Searching the standard library for `isNaN` or `isInf` does not reveal anything. There is a [blog post](http://akehrer.github.io/posts/getting-started-with-nim-2/) suggesting to use

```nim
proc cIsNaN(x: float): int {.importc: "isnan", header: "<math.h>".}
```

but is there really nothing in the standard library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard library does provide checking for NaN/inf, but under the generalized concept of `classify`, which is why it is easy to miss. To illustrate:

```nim
import math

# Inf and NaN literals are defined in system.nim as
# Inf* {.magic: "Inf".} = 1.0 / 0.0
# NaN* {.magic: "NaN".} = 0.0 / 0.0

let floatsToTest = [0.0, Inf, NaN]
for x in floatsToTest:
  echo x, " is NaN ", x.classify == fcNaN
  echo x, " is inf ", x.classify == fcInf
```

Output:

```
0.0 is NaN false
0.0 is inf false
inf is NaN false
inf is inf true
nan is NaN true
nan is inf false
```

`classify` can also test for other properties like `fcSubnormal`, `fcNegZero`, or `fcNegInf` (see [`FloatClass`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/math.html#FloatClass)).

Answer (score -1):

You can add your own function

```
import std/math

func is_number*(n: float): bool =
  let ntype = n.classify
  ntype == fc_normal or ntype == fc_zero or ntype == fc_neg_zero
```